# Software to print image from procedural script?

Tags: image-processing, image-editor, cad

It is surprisingly hard to search for and find a piece of software that handles a very specific need...

I am making a sort of slide rule that fits in a watch face, and I need a program where I could edit and then print the design (and preferably save as a format that I could send to specialty printer to get it printed on different materials). Not only that, I am *not* interested in calculating and then drawing in all of the measurements myself.

Here is a quick program I threw together to illustrate my project:

https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/spiral-log-scale-drawer/6483968785383424
[Don't worry, it'll run from inside the page, no downloads necessary]

I need some sort of image editor that allows for procedural generation scripts. Does anyone know of such a piece of software (hopefully freeware)?

Thanks